# how to create Data messages through kreait/firebase-php

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**FCM Documentation:**

> Message types With FCM, you can send two types of messages to clients:
>
> Notification messages, sometimes thought of as "display messages."
> These are handled by the FCM SDK automatically. Data messages, which
> are handled by the client app.

I have used the following ways to create push notification with [kreait/firebase-php](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php) but firebase console shows me all the sent message types are **Notification** not **Data**. how can send **Data** type messages?

```
$message = CloudMessage::withTarget('token', $deviceToken)
    ->withNotification(Notification::create('Title', 'Body'))
    ->withData(['key' => 'value']);

$message = CloudMessage::withTarget('token', $deviceToken)
    ->withData(['first_key' => 'First Value', 'second_key' => 'Second Value']);
```

Answer (score 2):

The console doesn't show messages with only a data payload.  The assumption is that these messages can be very frequent, and it would clutter the console with information that's not very useful.

If you want to know if the data message was sent, you should examine the result of the API call you used to send it.  I don't know about the module you're using, but the underlying [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages) makes this clear.

Comment: Result of the API is ok and is not problem. I'm using [kreait/firebase-php](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php)

Comment: As stated in the FCM console, `Messages include notification and data messages. Notification messages get displayed on end user devices. Data messages do not automatically generate a user-visible notification.` I think reporting panel also must separate them.